# How to add Facebook fan button in flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I want to add Facebook Fan button in my flash application? How to do this give me some example.not only add the like button i need to get the current users session also.

Thanks in advance,
Aravindakumar.T

Comment: I've downvoted this post, because you can easily find the answer by going to google or Bing and typing "Flash Facebook Like Button."

Comment: hi i know how to add fan button in website but in my flash application i need to add fan button and get the facebook users details like (username, userid)how to do this

Answer (score 1):

http://labs.byhook.com/2010/08/03/facebook-like-button-in-flash/

Comment: Facebook has a whole developer section that documents the available API